# What kind of system would have both discrete as well as continuous eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I have been given an example of a hydrogen atom, but i don't really understand how that works out, maybe someone can provide a better example.

Comment: the bounded states are discrete, the ionized ones are continuous

Comment: To add to what's said above, the hydrogen atom is a very nice example. Electrons in the orbitals of the hydrogen atom can only occupy discrete energies, 1s, 2s, 2p etc. However if you keep increasing the energy of the electron, at some point it's going to be released, at which point it's a free particle which has a continuum of energy states.

Comment: The [Finite potential well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) in one dimension is a simple example.